# Plotting a heat map for a data frame row that contains distance measures of agents

Tags: python, dataframe, heatmap

I have a data frame of 3000 rows x 101 columns like as follow:

```
Time   id0  id1  id2     ………… id99
1      1.71 6.99 4.01    ………… 4.98
2      1.72 6.78 3.15    ………… 4.97
.
.
3000   0.36 0.23 0.14    ………… 0.28
```

In fact the measures in the 100 columns (from id0 to id99) represent distances of agents in a global coordinate frame.

Is it possible to generate a heatmap for a given row in a way that the related (100x100) matrix contains the differences in distance between each pair of agent (id_i - id_j , with i and j /in {0..99}).

Comment: I'm not sure I undetstood right, but just using `plt.imshow(dataframe)` doesn't solve it?

Comment: @ilja this does not solve my problem. I want it for one row

Comment: I added an answer (if I'm right this time...) but you have to use `seaborn`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if I got it right now, that's what you'd like to have(?)

```
A = np.random.randint(0, 10, 10)
M = [A - x for x in A]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
seaborn.heatmap(M)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
#A
array([1, 6, 0, 1, 5, 8, 1, 1, 9, 0])


#M:
[array([ 0,  5, -1,  0,  4,  7,  0,  0,  8, -1]),
 array([-5,  0, -6, -5, -1,  2, -5, -5,  3, -6]),
 array([ 1,  6,  0,  1,  5,  8,  1,  1,  9,  0]),
 array([ 0,  5, -1,  0,  4,  7,  0,  0,  8, -1]),
 array([-4,  1, -5, -4,  0,  3, -4, -4,  4, -5]),
 array([-7, -2, -8, -7, -3,  0, -7, -7,  1, -8]),
 array([ 0,  5, -1,  0,  4,  7,  0,  0,  8, -1]),
 array([ 0,  5, -1,  0,  4,  7,  0,  0,  8, -1]),
 array([-8, -3, -9, -8, -4, -1, -8, -8,  0, -9]),
 array([ 1,  6,  0,  1,  5,  8,  1,  1,  9,  0])]
```

Comment: Hi @ilija, I think that I have not better explained the problem. Here I re-formulate it. Let assume that I have an array A(a0,a1, …., a99) of a cardinality 100. I want to generate a Matrix M of 100x100 that contains the differences between each pair element of A, i.e, each element m_ij /in M =a_i - a_j for each i /in A and for each j /in A. Then I want to generate a heat map for the data M.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I am tiered. I updated my answer (for example 10 elements instead of 100) or do I still got something wrong? :-)

Comment: Hi @ilija, That is exactly what I wanted. Thanks for your reply.